# Why isn't my tkinter window popping up even when there are no errors in my Python file using a MySQL database?

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-connector

I want to Create Main Portal which can accept Registration and Login data
input (Figure 1). User needs to successfully register their username and password in the
first step (Figure 2 and Figure 3). Then, user will login into the Login Portal (Figure 4) and
it will display the Welcome window. By Using Python And MySQL Database.

Why can't the windows popup when there's no error occurred in my python file to run tkinter?

```
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox

# connect to the database
mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host = 'localhost',
   user = 'root',
   password = '',
   database = 'lab4registrationlogindata'
)

# user registration
def register():
   # create the registration window
   reg_window = tk.Toplevel()
   reg_window.title("Registration Portal")
   
   # create the username label and entry box 
   tk.Label (reg_window, text = "Username :") .grid(row = 0, column = 0)
   username_entry = tk.Entry (reg_window)
   username_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
   
   # create the password label and entry box
   tk.Label (reg_window, text = "Password :").grid(row = 1, column = 0) 
   password_entry = tk.Entry (reg_window, show = "*")
   password_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
   
# submit registration
def submit_registration():
    #get the username and password from the entry boxes
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    # insert the user's information into the database
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    values = (username, password)
    mycursor.execute(sql, values)
    mysqldb.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo ("Success", "Registration successful!")
    reg_window.destroy()

    # create the register button
    submit_button = tk.Button (reg_window, text = "Register", bg = "light blue", command = submit_registration)
    submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

# login
def login():
    #create the login window
    login_window = tk.Toplevel()
    login_window.title("Login Portal")

    # create the username label and entry box tk.Label 
    tk.Label (login_window, text = "Username:").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    username_entry = tk.Entry (login_window)
    username_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    # create the password label and entry box
    tk.Label (login_window, text = "Password").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    password_entry = tk.Entry (login_window, show ="*")
    password_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
 
# submit login
def submit_login():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password  = password_entry.get()
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s" 
    values = (username, password)
    mycursor.execute(sql, values)
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    
    if result:
       messagebox.showinfo("Welcome", "Welcome, " + username)
       login_window.destroy()
    else:
       messagebox.showerror("Login", "Invalid username or password")
       
    # Submit button
    submit_button = tk.Button(login_window, text="Login", command = submit_login, bg = "light blue")
    submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    
    # Main Window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Main Portal")
    tk.Label(root, text = "Welcome to Main Portal", bg = "grey", font = "Arial 14").pack()
                
    # register & login buttons
    register_button = tk.Button(root, text="Register", bg = "light blue", command = register)
    register_button.pack(pady=10)

    login_button = tk.Button(root, text="Login", bg = "light blue", command = login)
    login_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Why can't the windows popup when there's no error occurred in my python file to run tkinter?  By Using Python And MySQL Database.

Comment: Are you intentionally declaring functions within functions within functions, or is that an indentation error?

Comment: Oh yes, indentation error. Thank you for pointing out my mistake

Comment: No worries! It happens to all of us. Just remember, you can [edit] your question at any time.

Comment: You define `register` and `login` functions, but you never call those functions.

Comment: Your code works fine if the indentation is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the identation error, I think your problem is that you forgot to apply your `TopLevel`'s `mainloop()`.

Here is your code fixed with a `TopLevel.mainloop()` added and a call to the `register()` method that I expect you left out by accident.

```
# user registration
def register():
    # create the registration window
    reg_window = tk.Toplevel()
    reg_window.title("Registration Portal")

    # create the username label and entry box
    tk.Label (reg_window, text = "Username :") .grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    username_entry = tk.Entry (reg_window)
    username_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    # create the password label and entry box
    tk.Label (reg_window, text = "Password :").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    password_entry = tk.Entry (reg_window, show = "*")
    password_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    reg_window.mainloop()
    
    # submit registration
def submit_registration():
    #get the username and password from the entry boxes
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    # insert the user's information into the database
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    values = (username, password)
    mycursor.execute(sql, values)
    mysqldb.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo ("Success", "Registration successful!")
    reg_window.destroy()

    # create the register button
    submit_button = tk.Button (reg_window, text = "Register", bg = "light blue", command = submit_registration)
    submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

# login
def login():
    #create the login window
    login_window = tk.Toplevel()
    login_window.title("Login Portal")

    # create the username label and entry box tk.Label
    tk.Label (login_window, text = "Username:").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    username_entry = tk.Entry (login_window)
    username_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    # create the password label and entry box
    tk.Label (login_window, text = "Password").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    password_entry = tk.Entry (login_window, show ="*")
    password_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

 # submit login
def submit_login():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password  = password_entry.get()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s"
    values = (username, password)
    mycursor.execute(sql, values)
    result = mycursor.fetchone()

    if result:
       messagebox.showinfo("Welcome", "Welcome, " + username)
       login_window.destroy()
    else:
       messagebox.showerror("Login", "Invalid username or password")

    # Submit button
    submit_button = tk.Button(login_window, text="Login", command = submit_login, bg = "light blue")
    submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    # Main Window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Main Portal")
    tk.Label(root, text = "Welcome to Main Portal", bg = "grey", font = "Arial 14").pack()

    # register & login buttons
    register_button = tk.Button(root, text="Register", bg = "light blue", command = register)
    register_button.pack(pady=10)

    login_button = tk.Button(root, text="Login", bg = "light blue", command = login)
    login_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

register()
```

I hope this helps, comment or update your question if I missed the point.